# How to Check if Script is run once device is booted?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, shell, scripts, mksh

I have a script I need to run once, and only once the phone is booted.

I have attempted init.qcom.post_boot.sh, init.sec.boot.sh, debuggerd, and finally mkshrc

While my script ran with debuggerd, I found that it ran every time debuggerd ran, which is not something I need to happen...  thus when I stumbled upon `/system/etc/mkshrc`   (the other 2 simply did not work)

What I found was, the script runs that one time, on boot... however, it also seems to run every time `adb shell` runs, along with (I assume) everytime shell is fired up... which is also undersireable.

So, what can I do in `/system/etc/mkshrc` to ensure my call to my script runs only the one time... at boot?

I thought about running a `while` loop to check for the `getprop sys.boot_completed` if it `==` 1 then dump a file somewhere, and through an `if` statement inside the looop to check for that file, if exists then exit, if not then run the next command...   however, everywhere I am allowed to dump that file, it persists between boots, so that `next command` never runs again.

**NOTE**
Does not need root to do this, nor does my script need root to run (yes, I have confirmed)

**CODE**

```
BB=/system/xbin/busybox
MYPID=/mnt/sdcard/.kev-run

while [ `getprop init.svc.bootanim` == "stopped" ] ; do 
    # if the run file does not exist, and we are stopped
    if [ ! -e $MYPID ]; then
        # run the scripts, then create the run file
        LOG=/mnt/sdcard/Download/kevs-scripts.log
        $BB rm -f $LOG;
        $BB echo "Launching Kevs Scripts" >> $LOG;
        MY_SCRIPT
        # write the run file so we aren't running this everytime this file runs
        touch $MYPID;
        sleep 1;
    fi
done

# if we are still booting, delete the run file
while [ `getprop init.svc.bootanim` != "stopped" ] ; do
    # we're not done booting, remove our makeshift pid file and sleep a second
    $BB rm -f $MYPID;
    sleep 1;
done
```

Seems to be off to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkshrc` is by definition run every time an **interactive** shell is started, so it’s the wrong place.

You really should hook up your script with Android’s init system instead. (Sorry, I can’t give details on how to do that; I don’t know the Android ecosystem well, I’m just `mksh`’s developer.)

Writing to a file in `tmpfs` (so it’s auto-removed on poweroff) is usually a good approach for a script to run only once. However, I’d be surprised if Android’s init system wouldn’t provide such a facility; it’s the ideal tool for your job.

Comment: yeah, noticed that.  I'm hooking into `debuggerd` again, and utilizing `setprop` to set a non-persistent "flag" now

Comment: i wish I could hook into init.   or even compile a kernel for it (which would be much much better), but alas... it's a Verizon, with a locked down bootloader so I'm limited LOL

Comment: Well, there’s [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6558/55417) but the accepted answer does not work on all phones as `/system/etc/init.d/` support is a CM(IIRC?) addition. [Patching `init.rc`](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167563/55417) seems to be the [generally correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5464713/2171120). In general, `service …\n\tdisabled\n\toneshot` [seems to work](http://k.japko.eu/android-init-exec.html); don’t forget to `chmod +x` it and copy to the correct partition beforehand.

Comment: I wish I could.  on a G935V, and it's bootloader locked, so root is the only thing we really have.  I ended up utilizing debuggerd as my "firing" mechanism, setting a "flag" via `setprop`   but what I'm finding now, is once `root` is removed, `setprop` no longer works.

My goal is to get some tweaks to work without having to root.   I have confirmed that some do indeed work, while some dont (which is expected), but the trick is getting them to fire off on boot... once :)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I can root/unroot my device at will.   Rooted, everything works just fine.  Unrooted, `debuggerd` throws a permission denied, so I think what I need to do is figure out the proper ownership, sepolicy, and context for it in order to get the permissions right... almost there LOL